# Check my work - General solution of a PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have just started learning partial differential equations. I am trying to solve this question, could anyone check if my calculations are correct?

**Question**: Classify the PDE:
$$ \sin(y) \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}+x \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}=\frac{x}{\phi} $$
and find its general solution. Find also the solution obeying $\phi=x^2$ on the line $y=3$.

**Attempt**: This PDE is first order, semi-linear.

The characteristic equations are:
$$\frac{dx}{\phi \sin(y)}=\frac{dy}{\phi x}=\frac{d \phi}{x}$$
The latter pair $\frac{dy}{d \phi}=\frac{d \phi}{x}$ gives:
$$y=\frac{x^2}{2}+C_1$$
The first and last then give:
$$\frac{d\phi}{dx}=\frac{x}{\phi \sin(y)}=\frac{x}{\phi \sin(\frac{x^2}{2}+C_1)}\Longrightarrow \phi \phi'=x\csc(\frac{x^2}{2}+C_1) \Longrightarrow \frac{1}{2}\phi^2=\ln(\tan(\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{C_1}{2}))+C_2$$
Hence,
$$\phi=\pm \sqrt{2\ln(\tan(\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{C_1}{2}))+A}$$
Each characteristic equation has a unique value of $C$, so we take $A=f(C)$, and the general solution is:
$$\phi=\pm \sqrt{2\ln(\tan(\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y}{2}-\frac{x^2}{4}))+f(y-\frac{x^2}{2})}=\pm \sqrt{2\ln(\tan(\frac{y}{2}))+f(y-\frac{x^2}{2})}$$
Finally, when $\phi=x^2$ on the line $y=3$, we have
$$x^2=\pm \sqrt{2\ln(\tan(\frac{3}{2}))+f(3-\frac{x^2}{2}}) \Longrightarrow f(3-\frac{x^2}{2})=x^4-2\ln(\tan(\frac{3}{2}))$$
So, the solution is
$$\phi=\pm \sqrt{2 \ln(tan(\frac{y}{2}))+x^4-2\ln(\tan(\frac{3}{2}))}$$
Please let me know if you find any mistake in my calculations. Thanks for your attention. I am looking forward to your reply.

Comment: You can always just check your result by differentiating and seeing if satisfies the PDE, then evaluating the solution to see if it satisfies the given data. Just so you know, from the wording 'the latter pair gives' doesn't make sense. The equality is $$\frac{dy}{\color{red}{\phi} x} = \frac{d \phi}{x} \implies dy = \phi d \phi \implies \frac{\phi^{2}}{2} - y = C_{1}$$

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake. Also thank you for the tip on how to check the solution of a PDE. I've tried it, and it worked!!